# How to sync time?

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set Ubuntu to synchronize my clock with a time server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228/how-to-set-ubuntu-to-synchronize-my-clock-with-a-time-server)

How to sync time in Ubuntu 10.10 (a GUI solution if possible)?

How to sync time in Ubuntu 10.04 Server (a console solution if possible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a server you can use ntpd or ntpdate .

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal and run `gnome-control-center` command . In the gnome control center select 'Time and Date' .  Select 'Keep synchronized with internet servers' in the 'configuration' option.