# Setting up ntp server

Tags: ntp

I have a few Jetson-TK1 boards that do not have a real-time clock and consequently loses their time whenever it is powered off. I would like to set each one so when they power on, their clock gets set.  The kicker is I may or may not be connected to the internet so I want my laptop (which also may or may not be on the internet) setup as an ntp server, so the Jetsons can get their time from it.

I am trying to follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488072/setting-up-a-standalone-ntp-server-on-ubuntu), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254826/how-to-force-a-clock-update-using-ntp), and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529799/is-there-a-way-to-make-ntpd-gq-run-faster) post. I can get the TK1 to update on startup, albeit somewhat slowly.  I cannot get it to get the time from my laptop (both are running Ubuntu).  In the first post it says to "specify your own server address" when setting up the server.  What should that address be? The address of the server I'm trying to setup (i.e. the machine's own IP address)? It seems like there should be more to setting up the server than what is given in that post.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

That configuration is for general use, you have gateway or  machine that get time from Internet. It is ok, if you are having an isolated network. So:

- Server ntp: Don't care about server IP. (You laptop in this case)

  Verify the you have ntp UDP port open:

  ```
  ~$ sudo netstat -ulp | grep :ntp
  udp        0      0 10.0.2.15:ntp           *:*                                 3437/ntpd       
  udp        0      0 localhost:ntp           *:*                                 3437/ntpd       
  udp        0      0 *:ntp                   *:*                                 3437/ntpd       
  udp6       0      0 fe80::b265:8d33:8fd:ntp [::]:*                              3437/ntpd       
  udp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:ntp       [::]:*                              3437/ntpd       
  udp6       0      0 [::]:ntp                [::]:*                              3437/ntpd
  ```

  or using `sudo netstat -ulpn | grep :123`

  If you have a firewall, allow packets to port `123`.
- Client ntp: Change its ntp server to your laptop IP.

  Default installation sync using `ntpdate` on network connection up:

  ```
  /etc/default/ntpdate
  ```

  If you setup `ntp` daemon, then change it here too:

  ```
  /etc/ntp.conf
  ```

  Verify connection to server:

  ```
  ~$ sudo ntpdate 91.189.94.4
   8 Jul 17:42:30 ntpdate[8968]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset 0.003846 sec
  ```