# Windows time jumps a few hours forward after using ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows-10, time

On my PC & Laptop I have a dual boot between Windows 10 & Ubuntu. Whenever I go into Ubuntu and then reset into Windows 10, Windows time jumps a few hours forward. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: One of your OSs (probably Windows) thinks the hardware clock is keeping local time.  The other OS thinks the hardware clock is on UTC+0, and adjusts for your timezone *when displaying* the time.  Ensure both OSs have the same view of what time the hardware clock is keeping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the fact that most Linux distributions set the *hardware clock* (BIOS) to UTC.  Using your **locale**, the system determines the *local time*.  This is the default and recommended setup.

On a Windows system, the hardware clock is set to the local time.  This will cause conflicts when dual-booting between Linux and Windows.

One solution is to tell Ubuntu to behave like Windows.  You can adjust this by editing `/etc/default/rcS`:

```
UTC=no
```

Another solution is to use [`timedatectl`](https://askubuntu.com/a/826844/13247) to acomplish this:

1. `sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 0 # Use UTC`
2. `sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 # Do *not* use UTC`

Alternatively, you can tell Windows that the hardware clock will be UTC:

1. [Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/185773/does-windows-7-support-utc-as-bios-time)
2. [Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/975717/does-windows-10-support-utc-as-bios-time)

I'd say to tell Windows how to act 'correctly', but in reality, you should leave your main OS as-is, and make your secondary OS conform to how the main OS acts.

Comment: There is no UTC in my rcS file?

Comment: In that case, use `timedatectl`.  I've added some information from [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/826844/13247).

Comment: Alright I set it to 1 now I will reply back the next time I go to Windows