# How to update system time behind a proxy?

Tags: proxy, time, ntp

So I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm finding that no matter what I do I cannot get the system time to properly sync with timeservers to get me up to date time. It's starting to prevent me from visiting websites as the certs need somewhat accurate time to match up. I've tried setting using timedatectl and installing ntp among a bunch of other things, I've found on here and elsewhere.

If it matters I'm behind a corporate proxy, but I have HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables set in my .bashrc

Any ideas people?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time information is retrieved using [Network Time Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol), which doesn't work through a http proxy.

Talk to your network administrator. Maybe there's already a NTP server on your local network. Or maybe he can install the NTP service in one of the production servers.

Then you only have to set its IP address in `/etc/default/ntpdate` or `/etc/ntp.conf`.