# When even ntpd doesn't sync time

Tags: sync, time, date, ntp

I have already tried the top 2 of most-voted answers to [How to force a clock update using ntp?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254826/how-to-force-a-clock-update-using-ntp) but none has worked.

Using ntpdate doesn't show any logs, and exits just fine, while ntpd gives the following output:

`4 Nov 13:49:28 ntpd[4754]: ntpd 4.2.8p8@1.3265-o Tue Jun  7 20:34:16 UTC 2016 (1): Starting
 4 Nov 13:49:28 ntpd[4754]: Command line: ntpd -gq
 4 Nov 13:49:28 ntpd[4754]: proto: precision = 0.055 usec (-24)
 4 Nov 13:49:28 ntpd[4754]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123
 4 Nov 13:49:28 ntpd[4754]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
 4 Nov 13:49:28 ntpd[4754]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1:123
 4 Nov 13:49:28 ntpd[4754]: Listen normally on 3 enp1s0 172.25.34.243:123
 4 Nov 13:49:28 ntpd[4754]: Listen normally on 4 wlp2s0 192.168.132.109:123
 4 Nov 13:49:28 ntpd[4754]: Listen normally on 5 lo [::1]:123
 4 Nov 13:49:28 ntpd[4754]: Listen normally on 6 enp1s0 [fe80::2ad2:44ff:feab:2d1e%2]:123
 4 Nov 13:49:28 ntpd[4754]: Listen normally on 7 wlp2s0 [fe80::162d:27ff:fee8:e407%3]:123
 4 Nov 13:49:28 ntpd[4754]: Listening on routing socket on fd #24 for interface updates
 4 Nov 13:49:29 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 52.66.76.135
 4 Nov 13:49:30 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 123.108.200.124
 4 Nov 13:49:36 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 123.108.200.124
 4 Nov 13:49:41 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 123.108.200.124
 4 Nov 13:50:33 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 125.62.193.121
 4 Nov 13:50:35 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 139.59.19.184
 4 Nov 13:50:37 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 139.59.19.184
 4 Nov 13:50:39 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 139.59.19.184
 4 Nov 13:51:38 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 123.108.200.124
 4 Nov 13:51:43 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 125.62.193.121
 4 Nov 13:51:44 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 52.66.76.135
 4 Nov 13:51:46 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 125.62.193.121
 4 Nov 13:52:44 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 139.59.19.184
 4 Nov 13:52:48 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 52.66.76.135
 4 Nov 13:52:49 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 125.62.193.121
 4 Nov 13:52:53 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 52.66.76.135
 4 Nov 13:53:52 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 123.108.200.124
 4 Nov 13:53:54 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 139.59.19.184
 4 Nov 13:53:55 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 2401:dc00:100:136::34
 4 Nov 13:53:58 ntpd[4754]: Soliciting pool server 125.62.193.121`

and carries on without stopping for a long time.
Yet none of these work. What should I do?

Using `timedatectl` provides:

`Local time: Fri 2016-11-04 13:56:00 IST
  Universal time: Fri 2016-11-04 08:26:00 UTC
        RTC time: Fri 2016-11-04 08:26:00
       Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no`

when the actual time is 20:26:00 IST or 14:56:00 UTC.

Comment: If you have physical access to the machine, just go into the BIOS and set the correct time there (be careful about whether your OS expects the hardware lock to be at UTC or local time).