# How do I force Ubuntu to resynchronize the system time?

Tags: 16.04, desktop-environments, lts, time, ntp

How can I force Ubuntu's system clock to pull and update time from a time server?

According to [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html#ntpdate) no longer supports `ntpdate` command (at least in Ubuntu Desktop LTS 16.04), and I've already tried using `timedatectl` as a command. That means that [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254826/how-to-force-a-clock-update-using-ntp) already answered is no longer useful for LTS 16.04.

Comment: Why does `timedatectl --adjust-system-clock` not resynchronize satisfactorily?

Comment: M. Becerra, I didn't know that was a solution

Answer (score 1):

`ntpdate` is in the `ntpdate` package, which you could install via `sudo apt install ntpdate`. Then read `man ntpdate`.

As mentioned in the comments, one needs to install the package `ntp` instead of `ntpdate` in Ubuntu 18.04+.

Remember to tell `ntp` to stop **before** running `ntpdate`:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ntp stop
```

and start `ntp` afterwards:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ntp start
```

Comment: Why did they remove it then?

Comment: on Xubuntu 18.04 i had to install `ntp` instead of `ntpdate` - `ntpdate` is still a package, but it doesn't install the `ntp` service, but the package named `ntp` installs the ntp service :o