# How to change ubuntu's server date and time via command line?

Tags: command-line, server, time, date

The Ubuntu server's current date and time is different from the time zone date and time. I have tried using:

```
sudo date "30 Sep 2015 4:43:42"
```

to change it but it did not change the date and time, just printed on terminal the date and time I changed, but when I executed:

```
sudo hwclock --show
```

The date and time is still the old one.

**What is the correct way to change date and time of Ubuntu Server?**

Comment: you really typed "sudo date newdate" - the word "newdate"?

Comment: Nope. I have edited my question. I typed "30 Sept 2015 4:43:42"

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can set the **system date** with this command:

```
sudo date --set="2015-09-30 10:05:59.990"
```

Then when using `date`, it should be showed correctly.

Now you should also the set **hardware clock** in the BIOS of the system, that the setting persists over a reboot (dureing the startup the system time is set to the value of the hardware clock). Do that with `hwclock`:

```
sudo hwclock --systohc
```

This gets the system clocks (sys) value and sets the hardware clock (hc). Check it with the `hwclock` command. Both `hwclock` and `date` should now show the same date and time.

---

To set your **timezone**, you can use this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

---

**BTW**: If you use a this machine as a server, I strongly recommend using an NTP-Client to **sync the time over network**. So you can guarantee that all your servers have the exactly same time set. This will sync the time while the machine runs. If you have applications which are dependent of synced time over server, I recommend the NTP-Daemon. The longer it runs in the background, the more precise is the time.

Comment: I missed the clock synchronization step. Thank you for your answer, it helped me!

Comment: 3 option helps, it changed **etc/timezone** =) like http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php !!! absolutely identical !!!

Comment: @VladimirCh Fortunatelly time zones names are stadarized, so we don't have to make any adjustments between systems. Oh, wait... there are some Microsoft version too...

Comment: I try to change but its not changing:-
 $ sudo date --set="2015-09-30 10:05:59.990"
Wed Sep 30 10:05:59 +0530 2015
$ date
Thu May 23 15:10:37 +0530 2019

Comment: this should not be the accepted answer since it mentions timezone explicitly

Comment: pls add sudo timedatectl set-ntp 0 to make sure NTP is disable, this one helps me

Comment: I get an error with `sudo date --set="2015-09-30 10:05:59.990"`: *invalid date '=2015-09-30 10:05:59.990'*. It works when I use the same command omitting '=':  `sudo date --set "2015-09-30 10:05:59.990"`

Comment: I tried `sudo date --set="2024-02-06 23:58:00.0"` but it did not work in Ubuntu 23.04 running in VirtualBox 7. Any idea why? I don't want to change the actual BIOS time, just within VirtualBox machine.

Answer (score 40):

1. Search for your timezone

```bsh
timedatectl list-timezones
```

2. Set your timezone

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone America/Toronto
```

3. Enable `timesyncd`

```bsh
sudo timedatectl set-ntp on
```

With this, time should be set and synchronized.

You can see more on this tutorial : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Best way to fix it without manually set hours and minutes! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

I dislike setting system time manually. So to fix this issue I had to combine two different answers.
To fix system time you have to use this code:

```
sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z"
```

as given in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81293/what-is-the-command-to-update-time-and-date-from-internet)
Then you sync the hardware clock with system clock using

```
sudo hwclock --systohc
```

as given by @chaos in this thread.

Answer (score 3):

Me helped:

---

### 1 - step (preparation)

```
 timedatectl set-local-rtc 0
 sudo timedatectl set-ntp 1
 sudo hwclock --systohc
 sudo timedatectl set-ntp 0
```

---

---

### 2 - step (set datetime)

```
sudo timedatectl set-time "06:24:00"
sudo timedatectl set-time "2020-04-23"
sudo hwclock --systohc
```

**or**

```
sudo date --set="2020-04-23 06:24:25.990"
sudo hwclock --systohc
```

---

---

### 3 - step (check datetime)

```
timedatectl
```

---

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Ubuntu-based servers on Amazon AWS. All of the SUDO DATE answers DID NOT WORK for me. SUDO DATE returned the new date as the output, but subsequent DATE invocations still shows the old date. Also, HWCLOCK did nothing but return an error.

The answer for me was:

`sudo timedatectl set-ntp false`

`sudo timedatectl set-time "date-time-string"`

Comment: Thanks man, saved my day !

Answer (score 1):

just type in

```
sudo date newdatestring
```

with **newdatestring** in the format nnddhhmmyyyy.ss

- nn: the (two digit) month (01 to 12)
- dd: the (two digit) day (01 to 31), with the regular rules for days according to month and year applying
- hh: the (two digit) hour (00 to 23)
- mm: the (two digit) minute (00 to 59)
- yyyy: the year; it can be two digit or four digit
- ss is two digit seconds (00 to 59). Notice the period ‘.’ before the ss.

But beside the date command, maybe you prefer the NTP "solution" (network time protocol): [Serverguide - NTP](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html), much easier to handle and more precise than setting the date by hand. You can use a cronjob or the ntp daemon (ntpd) to update you time every x hours/minutes...

Hope this helps!

Comment: invalid date range when i tried with "093005082015.15" which stands for 30 Sept  2015, 05:08:15

Comment: `sudo date "093005082015.15"`  working on mine.

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for the epoch seconds version

1. Set the current date and time

   ```bsh
   sudo date -s @1565864862
   ```
2. Get the current date and time

   ```
   date +%s
   ```

   outputs `1565864862`