# Changing server date

Tags: 14.04, server, vpn

I bought a shared VPN (Ubuntu 14.04) and installed my software.
I am using wordpress and mongo.
I need to read some data from mongodb converting seconds in time but my server is in New York and I am in Italy.

**How can I change time?**

Based on this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/679988/how-to-change-ubuntus-server-date-and-time-via-command-line) steps are:

- `sudo date --set` ------------------------------ partially works.
- `sudo hwclock --systohc` ----------------  doesn't work.

  Error is:

  ```
  Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
  ```

How can I succesfully change date/time?

Comment: Presumably the time is correct on your server and you just want to change the way dates and times are presented. That's done by changing the server's, or one or more user's, idea of which timezone they are in. What are the contents of the file `/etc/timezone` ?

Comment: Europe/Madrid. Time on my website is back of 5h.

Comment: If you type `TZ=Europe/Rome date`, does the time look correct?

Comment: no, nothing changes....