# date wouldn't change from console

Tags: server, date

I'm in need to temporarily change the date to debug one script and I run inti unexpected problem:

```
root@xxx:/# LC_ALL=C date
Wed Jan 31 17:09:02 EET 2018
root@xxx:/# LC_ALL=C date -s "2018-01-10 17:09:30"
Wed Jan 10 17:09:30 EET 2018
root@xxx:/# LC_ALL=C date
Wed Jan 31 17:09:28 EET 2018
```

**note:** I have a `ru_RU` locale, so I use `LC_ALL=C` for your convenience. Using the commands without `LC_ALL` change nothing.

I guessed that I do something wrong with syntax or reading `man` incorrectly, so I used instructions from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/679988/how-to-change-ubuntus-server-date-and-time-via-command-line/679995) thread and it solved nothing. attempts to set hwclock to match date resulted in nothing:

```
root@xxx:/# LC_ALL=C hwclock --systohc
root@xxx:/# LC_ALL=C hwclock --show
Wed Jan 31 17:18:17 2018  .451473 seconds
root@xxx:/# man hwclock
root@xxx:/# hwclock --set --date='2011-08-14 16:45:05'
root@xxx:/# LC_ALL=C hwclock --show
Sun Aug 14 16:45:09 2011  .389008 seconds
root@xxx:/# LC_ALL=C date
Wed Jan 31 17:21:07 EET 2018
```

How can I change date?

System:

```
root@xxx:/# cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
```

**UPDATE for @Yaron**

```
kovjr@xxx:~$ LC_ALL=C sudo date 120622432007.55
[sudo] password for kovjr: 
Thu Dec  6 22:43:55 EET 2007
kovjr@xxx:~$ LC_ALL=C date
Wed Jan 31 18:19:23 EET 2018
```

Comment: Is it regular ubuntu machine or ubuntu VM?

Comment: it is a regular

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://codeghar.wordpress.com/2007/12/06/manage-time-in-ubuntu-through-command-line/):

> **View Time**
>
> To view the current date and time, the following command will be
>   enough
>
> ```
> date
> ```
>
> **Set Time**
>
> To change time means to set a new time. To set time in Ubuntu (or any
>   Linux), just run the following command
>
> ```
> sudo date newdatetimestring
> ```
>
> where `newdatetimestring` has to follow the format `nnddhhmmyyyy.ss`
>   which is described below
>
> ```
> nn is a two digit month, between 01 to 12
> dd is a two digit day, between 01 and 31, with the regular rules for days according to month and year applying
> hh is two digit hour, using the 24-hour period so it is between 00 and 23
> mm is two digit minute, between 00 and 59
> yyyy is the year; it can be two digit or four digit: your choice. I prefer to use four digit years whenever I can for better clarity and less confusion
> ss is two digit seconds. Notice the period ‘.’ before the ss.
> ```
>
> Let’s say you want to set your computer’s new time to December 6,
>   2007, 22:43:55, then you would use:
>
> ```
> sudo date 120622432007.55
> ```

---

Example:

```
$ sudo date 120622432007.55
[sudo] password for xyz: 
Thu Dec  6 22:43:55 IST 2007
$ date
Thu Dec  6 22:43:56 IST 2007
$
```

Comment: it just doesn't stick: `root@xxx:/# LC_ALL=C date 011017502018.00  \n 
Wed Jan 10 17:50:00 EET 2018  \n 
root@xxx:/# LC_ALL=C date  \n 
Wed Jan 31 17:57:51 EET 2018`

Comment: @kovalenko-alex - as you can see from the updated answer, it do work (tested on ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: @kovalenko-alex - you forgot to execute `sudo` before the `date` command when you set the date

Comment: are you sure you are reading what I post? commands are executed from root (`sudo -i` was used before) as is clearly visible from code. It doesn't stick. It also shows that any variant I tried did output the correct date as a result of command, but it failed on the second call (`date` without arguments). So, the commands are correct, rights are correct, but something interferes. I want some hints on where to find the origin of interference.

Comment: @kovalenko-alex - comments aren't good place to hold logs, as it is very hard to read logs in comments. I missed the fact that you were running the command as root. Would you try to execute the two commands as descries in my answer (see example part of the answer)?

Comment: agreed.  post updated, still no luck

Comment: @kovalenko-alex - thanks for the updated question, we executed the same command and got different results....