# How to force an immediate clock/time synchronization/ntp update in 16.04?

Tags: time, 16.04, clock, ntp

It seems like the documentation at [the LTS server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/NTP.html) and and [community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime) may not have been updated for 16.04 yet. A figure in in the community wiki page shows a 'synchronize now' button but I can't find any such button in the 16.04 time and date settings. My time and date settings are set to automatically sync. Packages `ntp` and `ntpupdate` are not installed by default. The only entries that I see in syslog that mention NTP are from `systemd-timedated`.

Running `sudo apt install ntp; timedatectl set-ntp true` seemed to fix the time for now but I want to know what the "proper" way to do this in 16.04 would have been.

Maybe:

```
sudo ntpd -qg
```

Answer (score 11):

Using tlsdate:

```
sudo apt-get install tlsdate
sudo tlsdate -H mail.google.com
```

to make it auto

Make a script (e.g. ~/.update_time.sh):

```
sudo gedit ~/.update_time.sh
```

add these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
tlsdate -H mail.google.com
```

Save and close the file.  Modify the ownership:

```
sudo chmod 4711 ~/.update_time.sh
sudo chown root ~/.update_time.sh
```

Edit ~/.bash_profile:

```
sudo gedit ~/.bash_profile
```

and add this:

```
at -f ~/update_time.sh now + 1 minute
```

Save and close the file.

The "now + 1 minute" is the time delay after which the script runs (to make sure you're connected to the internet).  You may need to install at:

```
sudo apt-get install at
```

**WARNING**: The following uses the deprecated ntpdate package

I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/235/458247) and it worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install ntpdate
sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

to make it auto

Make a script (e.g. ~/.update_time.sh):

```
sudo gedit ~/.update_time.sh
```

add these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

Save and close the file.  Modify the ownership:

```
sudo chmod 4711 ~/.update_time.sh
sudo chown root ~/.update_time.sh
```

Edit ~/.bash_profile:

```
sudo gedit ~/.bash_profile
```

and add this:

```
at -f ~/update_time.sh now + 1 minute
```

Save and close the file.

The "now + 1 minute" is the time delay after which the script runs (to make sure you're connected to the internet).  You may need to install at:

```
sudo apt-get install at
```

Comment: Please don't promote usage of `ntpdate`. It is [deprecated](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate)!

Comment: tlsdate is no longer maintained nor recommended to use.

Comment: While I wholeheartedly agree, it's 2024 and still ntpdate is the always-working tool which does update the system time in an instant without configuration... it simply works.

Answer (score 3):

I had to use the "-s" option for tlsdate, since catch-22 the "tls" ssl connection would not work with a wrong date on the host here, due to google's ssl cert's date looking like a date in the future to the wrongly-time-configured host here.

```
    sudo tlsdate -s -H mail.google.com
```

Comment: tlsdate is no longer maintained nor recommended to use.