# How to get Ubuntu system with ntpd receiving data from GPS through USB and set clock accuracy?

Tags: server, ntp, gps

I have a hardware which is Ublox EVK-M8T kit, with the GPS antenna.

I also install the gpsd and ntp in the Ubuntu system.

I check to make sure all are working probably, such as:

1. turn of daemon os:

   ```
   sudo service gpsd stop
   ```
2. Remove any sockets gpsd might have left behind:

   ```
   sudo rm /var/run/gpsd.sock
   ```
3. make sure there is no instance of gpsd running:

   ```
   sudo killall -9 gpsd ntpd
   ```
4. find the current USB devices connected to the RPI:

   ```
   ls /dev/ttyACM0
   ```
5. check that your device is emitting data, and save MNEA message to logfile:

   ```
   gpsmon /dev/ttyACM0 -l logfile
   ```
6. and also work with:

   ```
   cgps -s
   xgps
   ```
7. reconfiguration file:

   ```
   sudo service ntp reload
   ```
8. see status overtime, show us all the clocks and what times are?

   ```
   sudo ntpq -p
   ```
9. check ntp status:

   ```
   service ntp status
   ```
10. change the server:

    ```
    sudo vim /etc/ntp.conf
    ```
11. and:

    ```
    ntpdate -d 192.168.1.231
    ```

....

Those are steps that I was trying to set up `gpsd` and `ntpd`, but I still do not understand, why do I have to do that?

How can I get an get Ubuntu system with ntpd receiving data from GPS through USB and set clock accuracy?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/228/how-to-set-ubuntu-to-synchronize-my-clock-with-a-time-server?rq=1 are similar your question.

Comment: The alleged duplicate is about syncing with ntp, but this asks about gps through usb.

Comment: @RonJohn you're right, thanks. I had misunderstood the problem.